# Get the ith word in a macro variable list

Tags: macros, sas

```
%let TableList = TableA TableH TableB TableG;
```

Words in `&TableList` are separated by `' '`.

How can I retrieve certain word to do the following?

I do not know the number of words in the `tablelist` and would like to get the nth word from the list.

Given `i = 4`,

```
data &&table&i.; /* &&table&i. will resolve to TableG */
set have;
[..];
run;
```

Comment: How did you generate that `&TableList`?  The answer may be in how you generated it.

Comment: I think `&TableList` is just defined by `%let` statement.

Comment: You're just typing it in?  Then why not type in multiple let statements (for table1 table2 table3 table4)?  (Also, figure out how to not type it in if you can - derive it from your data.  Data driven programming is much easier to manage.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to use the `%scan` function:

```
%put %scan(&tablelist,4,%str( ));
```

The third argument specifies that `%scan` should count only spaces as delimiters. Otherwise, it will also treat all of the following characters as delimiters by default:

```
. < ( + & ! $ * ) ; ^ - / , % |
```

Given the list you have, you can use a `%do` loop to add the macro variables to a list:

```
/* initialise a counter macro variable */
%let k = 1;

/* iterate through tablelist until a value is not found */
%do %until (%scan(&tablelist,&k,%str( )) = );
  %let table&k = %scan(&tablelist,&k,%str( )); 
  %let k = &k + 1;
%end;

%let i = 4;
%put &&table&i;
```

N.B. this code only works inside a macro definition (that is a block of code delimited by `%macro` and `%mend` statements.

Comment: If I don't know the number of words in the list, how can I get the last word?

Comment: At the end of the loop, the value of &k will be one greater than the number of words.

Comment: I would replace `%let k = &k + 1;` with `%let k = %eval(&k + 1);`. Otherwise k would become 1 + 1 after the first iteration instead of 2, which would result in an error when running `table&k`

Answer (score 2):

I would have done the same `%sysfunc(scan)` trick as @mjsqu and as to answer your remaining question - of getting the last word because you don't know the number of words in the list, the easiest way I can think of is using `array` like below

```
%let all=word1 word2 word3 word4 word5;

%macro test;
data _NULL_;
array x[*] &all.;
Num=dim(x);
call symput("Num_of_words",num);
run;
%mend;
%test;
```

Now you know the total number of words so can find out the last word as well.

Comment: countw is more simple.
%let all=word1 word2 word3 word4 word5;
%let num=%sysfunc(countw(&all));
%put &num;

Comment: Indeed. Put that as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for the purpose of selecting on the fly one word from the list, you should just make a macro, not try to set up macro variables.  Too much extra work to do all that business to make the various macro variables versus a one-line macro.

```
%let tableList=TableA TableB TableC TableD;

%macro selectTable(k=);
  %scan(&tablelist,&k)
%mend selectTable;

data %selectTable(k=4);
  set sashelp.class;
run;
```